# Using map interface to look for a value in a 'struct' like implementation of class

Tags: java

Im a beginner in Java, I am trying to implement a struct like data structure in Java using classes and I want to look for a match in that...This question might have been asked before, but Im not able to find it. Please help. The code is as follows:

```
public class operations extends DefFunctionHandler {  

public Integer stream;  
public Integer funct;  
public String name;  
public Integer funcgroup;  
public Integer source;  
}  
 //in another class
 public void execute(String x) {  

 List<operations> oplist = new ArrayList<operations>();  
 operations op = new operations();  

 for(int i=0; i< functi.size();i++){  
     op.stream = str.get(i);  
     op.funct = functi.get(i);  
     op.funcgroup = functigroup.get(i);  
     op.name = nme.get(i);  
     op.source = src.get(i);  

}  

 oplist.add(op);
 Map<String, List<operations>> map = new HashMap<String, List<operations>>();

 map.put(x, oplist);
 List<operations> ope = map.get(x);
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<operations>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      List<operations> value = entry.getValue();
      System.out.println(value);
    } 

}
```

As seen, I have a class `operations`, in which I have various fields. In another method called `execute`, I add values into those fields in the form of array. Now I get an input from the user for `name`, I want to search for it in the class/struct implementation and return the corresponding value for stream to the user. I understand that I have to implement a Map interface, but how do I do it? When I try to print `value`, I get `otf.operations@3934f69a` Is my implementation of Map Interface and get method correct? Im confused. Please help.

**EDIT** The code for the `execute` method now looks like this

```
 public void execute(String x) {

    Map<String,Operations> obs = new HashMap<String,Operations>();  

    for(int i=0; i< functi.size();i++){
        Operations op = new Operations();
        op.stream = str.get(i);
        op.funct = functi.get(i);
        op.funcgroup = functigroup.get(i);
        op.name = nme.get(i);
        op.source = src.get(i);

        obs.put(op.name, op);       

}
    System.out.println(obs.get(x));

}
```

Comment: try for example in the System.out.println(value.get(0))

Comment: @darijan No I still get the same junk value. May be the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Also, `operations op = new operations();` and `oplist.add(op);` have to be inside the for loop!

Comment: @Sebastian Is my implementation of Map interface correct?

Comment: I added my answer.  Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print a list:

```
System.out.println(value)
```

where value is a `List<operations>`. What you would like to do is to print the values of that list. Then do something like:

```
for (operations o : value) {
    System.out.println(o.stream);
    System.out.println(o.name);
}
```

**EDIT** the code you need:

```
public void execute(String x) {


      ArrayList<operations> ops= new ArrayList<operations>();
      for(int i=0; i< functi.size();i++) {
         operations op = new operations();
         op.stream = str.get(i);
         op.funct = functi.get(i);
         op.funcgroup = functigroup.get(i);
         op.name = nme.get(i);
         op.source = src.get(i);
         ops.add(op);
      }


     Map<String,ArrayList<operations>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<operations>>();
     map.put(x, ops);

     for (operations operation : map.get(x)) {
         System.out.println(operation.name);
     }

}
```

Comment: But how do I access name and stream from the list of values? It does not allow me to do that!

Comment: Check again please. The answer has been edited in this line `for (operations o : value) {`

Comment: oh sorry..now it works..but it returns to me all the values and not just the match for x i.e the string the user is looking for..is my Map implementation of get method correct?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't iterate over `map.entrySet()` at all but only over `ope` List in the way I have described.

Comment: ok that again returns the entire array of names or streams. I think my Map Interface's put method is wrong. How do I input just the List<operations> and later search for String X (i.e Name) in that?

Comment: Create map like this `Map<String, operations>` instead of the `Map<String, List<Operations>>`. Also, disregard (remove) the `oplist`, you dont need it. Put it in a map like this `map.put(x, op)`. Then, you can get the name with `map.get(x).name`.

Comment: But I have a problem now, when I print the map.get values for all fields, only the last element in the array is returned. Why is that so?

Comment: Add this: to the end `System.out.println(map.get(x).stream); System.out.println(map.get(x).funct); System.out.println(map.get(x).name); System.out.println(map.get(x).funcgroup); System.out.println(map.get(x).source);`

Comment: But I mean the problem is, whatever input I give for x(String input from user) to Map, I always get the last element of stream/funct.source as stored in op. Why is that?

Comment: The Map does not do a search for x at all, it always returns the last element in the array of op for whatever field I ask for.

Comment: Okay, move the map out of the function. Let it be a class field: `private Map<String, operations> map= new HashMap<String, operations>();` In one method populate the map with operation for some x (the `put` part), and in another just retrieve values for some x (the `get` part of your code). `x` has to be unique for all operations. If one `x` has more operations, then you have to switch back to Map<String, ArrayList<operations>> from the beginning of your solution and retrieve like: `for (Operation op : map.get(x)) { System.out.println(op.name); }`

Comment: Thanks for help with the code! But it is still the same story, I get only the last value of the array even with ArrayList<operations> code that you suggested :( :(

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the way the Map put or get method is implemented. Is there any other way to do this..without use of Maps?

Comment: There is no problem with the Map, and "the better way" depends on the use case. For this example, the Maps are just perfect. Check whether you pass in the correct values.

Comment: Thanks again for patiently answering my questions! I too think that the map is the best for this case. I forgot to mention that I get the output(using print statement inside for loop as you suggested) printed 20 times on the screen...that is the size of the `functi.size` for the other for loop where I add data to `op` and  `ops`. So this means that the get(x) returns all the 20 values and not just the match. And again the 20 values are not the correct ones, but just the last value in the `op` or `ops` array.

Comment: And yes the values that are passed are correct. I checked that!

Comment: Are you sure that this line `operations op = new operations();` is inside the for loop?

Comment: Im really sorry..you were right! that was not inside the for loop. And now I get all the values again, but not the match alone. So it is 20 values again...like I input to the array `op`.

Comment: Well, I can't help you there. You need different `x` for every value of the `operations` instance, and AGAIN the Map<String, operations>. But you have to figure out that one yourself.

Comment: When we do `map.put(x,ops)`, are we not assigning all the ops with the same key? May be that is the mistake here

Comment: Yes we are. We are assigning the list of all ops to the same key. If you call process execute method again with different x and different values in str, functi, nme, etc.. you would get different results for different values of x. But I can't help you much there since I don't know where are those lists coming from, where is the x coming from and what are you trying to do...

Comment: Ya I understand now. I will think abt the solution from here on :) Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: You could accept the answer at least. Not that I didn't spend half of my working time on you :))

Answer (score 1):

First of all `value` is `List<Operations>`, so to iterate over each, you can do

```
for(Operations o : value) {
   System.out.println(o);
}
```

If you get a chance to see the implementation of `System.out.printlin(object)`, it will print `object.toString()`

So  `otf.operations@3934f69a` is the string returned by the method `toString()` which is by default inherited from `java.lang.Object` class (since all classes implicitly extend `Object`). The `toString()` of `java.lang.Object` looks like this

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

to change this behavior, in your Operations class, you need to override toString() method

```
class Operations {

  @Overrides
  public String toString() {
     return name;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A map can be thought of as a list with labels on each of the items, so that you can easily find an item in the list by its label.  What is the label?  Well, in the context of Java it is called a key, and can be many types.  Most times it is a String, but it can also be any object which implements `equals(Object obj)` and `hashCode()` properly (which String already does).

Lets see how you would insert objects into a list:

```
List<operations> list = new ArrayList<operations>();
for(int i=0; i functi.size(); i++) {
  operations op = new operations();
  op.stream = str.get(i);  
  op.funct = functi.get(i);  
  op.funcgroup = functigroup.get(i);  
  op.name = nme.get(i);  
  op.source = src.get(i);

  list.add(op);   
}
```

Notice here that *inside the loop*, I am calling new `operations` and then I am adding it to the list.  This is because I want to create a new instance of `operations` and add it to the list *for* each potential operation I can create.

What would happen if I used the same instance?  I would set its members again and again with different values, and insert that same instance into the list (yes, a list can contain the same instance many times over).  What it would seem like is that you inserted a list containing `operations` all with the same value (which happen to coincide with the last operation).  This is because when you set the property of an instance, all references to the same instance get changed as well (think pointers).  So, in other words, be sure to create a new instance each time (You don't have to worry about deleting it later.  That gets done automatically).

In order to use a map, you only have to change the logic ever so slightly.  Rather than call add, you use put, and you must provide its key.  When you need it later, you must provide its *key* rather than its number.  Here is how you would add it to a map:

```
Map<String, operations> map = new HashMap<String, operations>();
for(int i=0; i functi.size(); i++) {
  operations op = new operations();
  op.stream = str.get(i);  
  op.funct = functi.get(i);  
  op.funcgroup = functigroup.get(i);  
  op.name = nme.get(i);  
  op.source = src.get(i);

  map.put(op.name, op);   
}
```

Later, to retrieve a value, I only have to do `map.get("juggling")`, and if it exists in the map, it will give me that particular instance of `operations`, otherwise it will give me `null`.

You should note several things here:

- In this way, operations with duplicate names are *overridden*.  If you have no duplicates, there is no problem.  Otherwise, you may consider making your key more specific or making your map hold a `List` of `operations` instances (on first put for that key, you must create the list instance and add it to the map).
- This approach is ideal if you access only with its key.  If you want to also access it as a list, you should prefer `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` (don't use unless you think you will require both, as it is slightly more expensive, but it maintains insertion order).

Also, a couple best practice notes:

- Consider adding setters and getters to `operations`.  It may not help you in this particular program, but it is best practice and will help you in other programs without a doubt.
- Java class names start with a capital letter normally.  Method names and member names are camelCase.
- You usually do not make Java class names "plural" unless it is a container of some sort.  In other words, I would expect a single operation to be called `Operation`, and a list of `Operation` instances to be called `Operations`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil! It works now...Thanks for taking time to explain the basics to me! Means a lot to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

As you named it "struct" I guess you come from C. In Java you just have to create a "bean" which is an object which only has getters and setters (the attributes are usually declared as private so you'll need a getX() and setX(value) methods to access and modify them). That's your "operations" class, more or less.

Class names always start with capital letters (Java convention).

if you need to find quickly a bean/struct by a value, then store it in a Map:

```
Map<String, operations> map = new HashMap<String, operations>();
map.put(myOperation.getName(),myOperation);
```

Then, you can obtain that bean just writing `map.get(name).`

Last thing, you have to implement the method `toString()` in any object you want write easily

EDIT: I think you don't need a list, just put directly each element in a map and remove the list, something like:

```
Map<String,operations> oplist = new HashMap<String,Operations>();  
 operations op = new operations();  

 for(int i=0; i< functi.size();i++){  
     op.stream = str.get(i);  
     op.funct = functi.get(i);  
     op.funcgroup = functigroup.get(i);  
     op.name = nme.get(i);  
     op.source = src.get(i);
     oplist.put(op.name,op);  //You forgot this! it must be in the loop

}
```

Then you can find any operation by name (I'm supposing name is unique)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Im from C and I understand your concept of get and set methods. Indeed that is how I fill in the values in the array. But can you tell me, how I can fill the Map interface with just the List<operations> and later use get method to search?